# How to remove repeating code in this method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, modularity

```
private static Game[] getMostPlayedGamesDo(int Fetch, int CategoryID)
{
    Game[] r;
    using (MainContext db = new MainContext())
    {
        if (CategoryID == 0)
        {
            var q = db.tblArcadeGames.OrderByDescending(c => c.Plays).Take(Fetch);
            r = new Game[q.Count()];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var g in q)
            {
                r[i] = new Game(g);
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var q = db.tblArcadeGames.Where(c=>c.CategoryID == CategoryID).OrderByDescending(c => c.Plays).Take(Fetch);
            r = new Game[q.Count()];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var g in q)
            {
                r[i] = new Game(g);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

I can't seem to define `q` outside the scope of the `if`, and I can't insert the returned values to the array outside the scope of the if!  Not sure how to remove repeating code in this simple instance?

Comment: Can you not make q a concrete type? What is q in both instances? Must have a common base?

Comment: @Kiwi sorry I don't really understand it too well, I've always defined my linq to sql queries as var types

Comment: @Tom, what is the Class for tblArcadeGames generated in your dbml? If it's tblArcadeGame then the type of q can be List<tblArcadeGame> or IQueryable<tblArcadeGame>. Look at Kirks Woll's  answer and mine.

Comment: Setting a break point after the call and inspecting the type should tell you what q is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what the type of `q` is -- but deducing from your usage:

```
db.tblArcadeGames.OrderByDescending(...)
```

Presumably it's an entity class from Linq-To-Sql or Entity Framework.  In that case, you *do* have a concrete entity defined, presumably named `tblArcadeGame`.  Therefore, move `q` out of the scope by not using `var`:

```
IQueryable<tblArcadeGame> q;
if (CategoryID == 0)
{
    q = db.tblArcadeGames.OrderByDescending(c => c.Plays).Take(Fetch);
}
else
{
    q = db.tblArcadeGames.Where(c=>c.CategoryID == CategoryID).OrderByDescending(c => c.Plays).Take(Fetch);
}
r = new Game[q.Count()];
int i = 0;
foreach (var g in q)
{
    r[i] = new Game(g);
    i++;
}
```

As you can see, the repeated code is now seen only once.

**P.S.** Tools like ReSharper are fantastic for this sort of thing.  Using it, with one keystroke you can toggle between the `var` version and that using explicitly named types.

Answer (score 1):

You should really just explicitly type q. But this may let you get away without it (ternary operator will enforce it for you).

```
var q = CategoryID == 0 ? db.tblArcadeGames.OrderByDescending(c => c.Plays).Take(Fetch)
                        : db.tblArcadeGames.Where(c=>c.CategoryID == CategoryID).OrderByDescending(c => c.Plays).Take(Fetch);

r = new Game[q.Count()];
int i = 0;
foreach (var g in q)
{
    r[i] = new Game(g);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume q is type IQueryable.

```
private static Game[] getMostPlayedGamesDo(int Fetch, int CategoryID)
{
    var q = db.tblArcadeGames;
    if (CategoryID != 0)
    {
        q = q.Where(c => c.CategoryID == CategoryID);
    }
    q = q.OrderByDescending(c => c.Plays).Take(Fetch);
    return q.Select(g => new Game(g)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<tblArcadeGame> q;
    /* object q; */


    if (CategoryID == 0)
    {
        q = db.tblArcadeGames.OrderByDescending(c => c.Plays).Take(Fetch).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        q = db.tblArcadeGames.Where(c=>c.CategoryID == CategoryID).OrderByDescending(c => c.Plays).Take(Fetch).ToList();
    }

        r = new Game[q.Count()];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var g in q)
        {
            r[i] = new Game(g);
            i++;
        }
```

I'll assume `q` is `List<tblArcadeGame>`

Comment: Two things. You can't have a var without a rhs, and even if you could in this example q would be three different variables

Comment: Doesn't work, `Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized` on the first `var q;`.  This is what's causing me difficulty as it's easy to remove repeating code but not so when linq is involved.

Comment: I don't know... I assume all codes he provided are correct. I just reconstructed it.